# Setting the default page for ASP.NET (Visual Studio) server configuration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, configuration

When I build and run my application I get a directory listing in the browser (**also happens for sub folders**), and I have to click on Index.aspx.  It's making me crazy.

Visual Studio 2008
ASP.NET Development Server 9.0.0.0

Comment: This same question (asked after this one) also appears, with a different answer, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398565/change-default-default-aspx-to-index-aspx-on-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Refer @Philippe Leybaert answer  that says "Go to the project's properties page, select the "Web" tab "

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The built-in webserver is hardwired to use Default.aspx as the default page.

The project must have atleast an empty `Default.aspx` file to overcome the Directory Listing problem for `Global.asax`.

:)

Once you add that empty file all requests can be handled in one location.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Response.Write("hi@ " + this.Request.Path + "?" + this.Request.QueryString);
        this.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        this.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        this.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39):

Right click on the web page you want to use as the default page and choose "Set as Start Page" whenever you run the web application from Visual Studio, it will open the selected page.

Comment: Yup, that works for the start page, but when I browse to anything in a sub folder I get a folder listing again.

Answer (score 12):

Go to the project's properties page, select the "Web" tab and on top (in the "Start Action" section), enter the page name in the "Specific Page" box. In your case **index.aspx**

Comment: Yup, that works for the start page, but when I browse to anything in a sub folder I get a folder listing again.

Comment: It's not possible to specify a default page in Visual Studio's internal webserver (Cassini)

Comment: It's working as expected for several of the other developers in my group

Comment: The built-in webserver is hardwired to use Default.aspx as the default page. Maybe your team members are using Default.aspx instead of index.aspx? Or maybe they're using the local IIS on their machine for development.

Comment: Thanks, now if I can only get it to start the web project all the time instead of the child projects when running the solution

Answer (score 9):

Similar to zproxy's answer above I have used the folowing code in the Gloabal.asax.cs to achieve this:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            Server.Transfer(Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "index.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("/"))
        {
             Server.Transfer("~/index.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is not quite right. If the user goes to "site.com/account/" the user will be redirected to "/index.aspx", instead of "/account/index.aspx"

Comment: "Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery." - Charles Caleb Colton

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to add a DefaultDocument settings in the Web.config.

```
  <system.webServer>
   <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="DefaultPage.aspx" />
    </files>
   </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running against IIS rather than the VS webdev server, ensure that Index.aspx is one of your default files and that directory browsing is turned off.

Comment: Nope, I'm running the VS webdev server.

Answer (score 0):

This One Method For Published Solution To Show SpeciFic Page on startup.

Here Is the Route Example to Redirect to Specific Page...

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "YourSolutionName.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

By Default Home Controllers Index method is executed when application is started, Here You Can Define yours.

Note : I am Using Visual Studio 2013 and "YourSolutionName" is to changed to your project Name..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what framework you are using but in ASP.NET MVC you can simply go to the App_Start folder and open the RouteConfig.cs file. The code should look something like this:

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

You can change the landing page on the last line of code there after `defaults`.