# Change Default "Default.aspx" to "Index.aspx" on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, asp.net-3.5, default

Whenever I create a new Web Form on Visual Studio 2010, the default name is always "Default.aspx". This is a slight pain as I'm having to change it to "Index.aspx" each time.

How can I change this so that "Index.aspx" is the default name?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean project instead of form? It asks for the name of new forms.

Comment: It does ask for the name, but the name is pre-filled with 'Default.aspx' whereas I wish it to be 'Index.aspx'. Sorry if I didn't make that clear in my original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can by modifying the associated .vstemplate [DefaultName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bhe4xe9.aspx) element. For example, you might find the webform template you need to modify in a directory similar to the following: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033. Each template file is managed within a zip file like WebForm.zip.  Unzip the contents, modify the .vstemplate DefaultName element and reapply the changes to the same templates folder. Your updates should be reflected in Visual Studio. (You might need to restart VS.)

As an alternative, you should consider creating your own template (based off the original) instead of modifying the default template.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way do to that in Visual Studio. You can only do that in IIS.

But, you can define a Startpage in the Property-Pages (Web) of the ASP.NET Webpplication.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not cover all scenarios I have used the folowing code in the Gloabal.asax.cs to achieve this:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            Server.Transfer(Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "index.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

*You must remember to remove this code when deploying the code (or wrap in DEBUG statements)!

Comment: Thanks Johnathan. Why must I remember to remove it before deploying? I can't rely on my memory lol so I'll probably wrap it in an "IF (SiteIsLive)" statement or something

Comment: I suspect that it would be far more efficient to let IIS handle the default pages (such as index.aspx) rather than using this code on every request.  Alternatively (and probably advised if you suffer forgetfulness) ;)  you could wrap this code in `#if (DEBUG)` which means that it will only execute when running the code in debug mode.  You can find [more details on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Comment: A note on this approach is that the `HttpContext.Current.Session` is not yet initialized after the transfer call. The transfer does however (by default, but can be removed) pass all the variables.