# start Page functionality does not work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net website,
and i have set 1 page "search.aspx" as start page,

and when i type url like this:" http://localhost/websitename/subfolder/Search.aspx"

it opens properly.

but i want it to open when i type : " http://localhost/websitename/" like this only,

and i have set the "search.aspx" as start page.

Can anyone please help,

i tried changing property pages also.

but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Start Page in Visual Studio just refers to the page which will be opened when you Run your solution.

When running localhost, the "Default Page" for ASP.NET [is always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398565/change-default-default-aspx-to-index-aspx-on-visual-studio-2010) Default.aspx (unless you do a lot of workarounds).

In IIS [you have control over this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) however, by setting "Default Documents".

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the start page in IIS. Here is a tutorial

http://www.ehow.com/how_4532283_set-start-page-microsoft-iis.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two points to consider here.

Firstly, you need to look in IIS and see what "Default Documents" you have set up for that web application.  If "search.aspx" is not listed then that page won't be served as a default page for that folder.  If you add "search.aspx" as a default document then your page will show if you navigate to websitename/subfolder/

Secondly, are you providing a way to traverse to the subfolder?  IIS will be looking for the default document in the ..websitename/ folder.  If the default document was "default.aspx" you need to add some sort of redirect to the subfolder.

Alternatively, set the subfolder as the root folder of your website (unless you need to go up one level).

Comment: how to set the subfolder as root folder?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a default document for the page in IIS, or make the default page redirect to the search page, alternatively [use routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

[Here is](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true) how you set default document in IIS6.

Since you want a page in a subfolder to be the default your easiest path is either a redirect or routing.

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing this.

1. take a blank index.htm page and add meta tag for redirecting to your starting page:

   ```
   <head>
         <title></title>
     <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://localhost/websitename/subfolder/Search.aspx">
   </head>
   ```
2. Make default page(index.htm) in IIS for the website.

   - [IIS7](http://www.netomatix.com/development/IIS7Configuration3.aspx)
   - [IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true)
3. use following setting in web.config:

   ```
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
               <add value="index.htm" />
            </files>
       </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
   ```

reference:[Default Document](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument)