# Default page in godaddy.com

Tags: asp.net, web-config

How I can set the default I wrote in the web.config this code and it doesn't work

```
<!--<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear/>
    <add value="~/HomePage.aspx"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>-->
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
      <urlMappings>

  <add url="~/Default.aspx" mappedUrl="~/HomePage.aspx"/>
</urlMappings>
```

Comment: these existing questions may be of help : [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125280/setting-the-default-page-for-asp-net-visual-studio-server-configuration) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022949/change-default-startup-page-asp-net-windows-hosted-godaddy)

Answer (score 1):

Put urlMappings tag inside the system.web tag like:

```
    <system.web>
            <urlMappings enabled="true">
                 <add url="~/Default.aspx" mappedUrl="~/index.aspx"/>
            </urlMappings>
</system.web>
```