# How to set the default webpage in VB.Net web project

Tags: vb.net

I have a class API, and a function test in my web project. To call this function, I type the link http://localhost/api/test in my browser.

Is it possible to call a default page, for example index.html, if I just call the class without the function like: http://localhost/api?

The project doesn't use ASP.NET.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125280/setting-the-default-page-for-asp-net-visual-studio-server-configuration  See the second solution--just right click on the file that you want to be the default and select "Set as Start Page"

Comment: Thanks for reply. This Solution just work for the Server in Visual Studio but i will use it on an external IIS.

Comment: The IIS settings have a default page configuration.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753615%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I tried this already, but it doesn't work for me. I think the reason is, that the Index.html is in the application folder, but the site has to stay there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a redirect with the following code in my web.config file.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
         <add wildcard="*api" destination="/index.htm" />
         <add wildcard="*api/" destination="/index.htm" />
      </httpRedirect>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's fine for while you're debugging. But when you actually deploy to a live web server this is done in the IIS configuration, which may or not accept your web.config option.